# Knockout js list with dirty objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm learning Knockout and I'm stuck on what seems to be a fairly trivial issue. Below is some modified code but most of it is from the Pluralsight course. I'm using MVC4 and all my data is coming from a controller in JSON.

```
Public Function GetData() As ActionResult

    Return Json(dataContext.GetData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

End Function
```

Here is my view

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
        <li >
            <input type="text" id="name"  data-bind="value: name" />

        </li>
</ul>
```

And my view model :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    ko.dirtyFlag = function (root) {
        var result = function () { },
            _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root))

        result.isDirty = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            return _initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
        });

        result.reset = function () {
            _initialState(ko.toJSON(root));
        };

        return result;
    };


    function Customer(data) {
          this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
          this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
          this.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(this);
}



    var ViewModel = function (items) {
          var self = this;
          this.items = ko.observableArray([]);

          this.save = function () {
            alert("update");
                };

          this.addNew = function () {
            alert("add");
                };

          this.deleteItem = function () {
           alert("delete");
                 };

          this.dirtyItems = ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function (item) {
                return item.dirtyFlag.isDirty();
            });
           }, this);

          this.isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.dirtyItems().length > 0;
          }, this);

        $.getJSON("/home/GetCustomers", function (allData) {
                    var mappedLoadouts = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new     Customer(item) });
                    self.items(mappedLoadouts);
                });
          };

            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Please note this code has been changed to simplify the example.

My first question is, why doesn't this work? I keep getting a 'DirtyItems' can be found, can anyone tell me why? I can't see a scope issue because I'm referring to customers in the same context.

Also, all of the help that I found so far uses a different approach to the Javascript all together. Just like this similar question [Best way to get only modified rows from observableArray (when there is bulk edit option)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662626/best-way-to-get-only-modified-rows-from-observablearray-when-there-is-bulk-edit). When I attempted to rebuild my viewmodel to follow this example, I received an error on the foreach : Customers (same error as the DirtyItems).

This was a promising question, but the answer again used the other Javascript approach [Knockout dirty flag event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896244/knockout-dirty-flag-event)

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I'd guess the issue is that Knockout needs you to qualify DirtyItems since you're using it within a function.

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.DirtyItems)"></div>
```

If you're still having issues, you may want to post a fiddle reproducing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. That fixed the initial issue, but I still wasn't able to get it all working correctly, so I ended up taking the other approach of declaring my viewmodel using a function. I've updated my question with working code.

Comment: Ok, in your new example, you said, "I received an error on the foreach : Customers." What is the error?

Comment: that was in the old example, I'm not sure what was causing it. I took your advice and rebuilt it as a fiddle before adding it into my mvc project. While I was rebuilding it that issue went away. I'm guessing it has to do with object literal declaration that I was trying to use initially.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps since this answer fixed the initial issue, you could mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's part of the problem, but there's a typo in your DirtyFlag code:

```
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.**Customerss**, function (item) {
```

It could be what Judah said, about needing $root.  It also could be a binding/timing issue.  What is the actual JavaScript message, is DirtyItems "undefined"?

As a personal preference, I try to avoid such function calls embedded in the HTML, so I would move the "ko.toJSON(DirtyItems)" call to a computed function and bind to that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The typo wasn't the problem, that was just an editing mistake, but good catch. Yes, dirtyItems was undefined.  The function call was just for testing and taken from one of the knockout demos. I've updated my question with working code. I'm still not sure why the first approach wasn't working, but this will do!